# Java Tomcat enable caching

Tags: java, tomcat, caching

What is the best way to set up caching on tomcat?

Also how caching works?Is it url based,dir based or what?
I need url specific caching so the database don't make the same calculations for the same url's

Comment: Are you intending to cache the HTTP responses from the server for a given URL with the same querystring or POST parameters?

Comment: you might want to update the question to state that. I think people might misunderstand the question and it might be closed.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds Sorry i misunderstood you probably.Are you talking for browser caching?Because i'm talking for server caching

Comment: I was referring to server-side caching employed in the data center.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way, is to use a dedicated web cache provider. Tomcat does not have one OOTB, but you could employ [Apache with mod_cache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/caching.html) (and obviously mod_jk). In this configuration, Apache tends to act as a proxy-cache that caches the dynamic content served by Tomcat; you will have to ensure that Tomcat serves the right headers to ensure that Apache will cache the responses.

There are other commerical web-cache solutions, but they're typically used for high-end uses.

You could also employ Squid instead of Apache, to act as a reverse proxy that is also capable of serving cached content; in this case, Squid performs caching of the dynamic content.

If you do not wish to invest in an additional server, like the above solutions suggest, you might consider using [EHCache to perform web page caching](http://ehcache.org/documentation/web_caching.html) on Tomcat itself.

**Related**

1. [Java Web Application: How to implement caching techniques?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699996/java-web-application-how-to-implement-caching-techniques)

Comment: Thanks i already have apache as a proxy but a few attempts with mod_cache failed.Can you point me to some examples?

Comment: Well, I just noticed this link - http://blogs.sun.com/trawick/entry/caching_dynamic_content_with_apache . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat doesn't support what you want out of the box, so you'll need some extra stuff. I'm not fully aware of all `mod_cache` capabilities but if you're not using Apache, [OSCache](http://www.opensymphony.com/oscache/) can do what you're requesting.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the Expires Filter?

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Expires_Filter

See also this question:

[Enable caching in Tomcat 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539838/enable-caching-in-tomcat-6)