# Enable caching in Tomcat 6?

Tags: java, tomcat, caching, servlets

I need to increase the page load speed. In google page speed I have this issue:

The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the following resources.

So I should add expiration date to header to force browser to cache static content in the page. Is there any solution for this?

I use tomcat 6.0.26.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this, can you say more about how you're doing things (plain servlets? spring?)? What have you tried?

Comment: Tomcat 7 has the ExpiresFilter to do that. I ported that filter to Tomcat 6. See https://github.com/bnegrao/ExpiresFilter

Answer (score 3):

**One Solution using spring framework**

You need to write a filter something similar to this one:

```
@WebFilter(dispatcherTypes = { YourDispatcherTypes }, urlPatterns = { "*.jsp","/yourresourcename/*", "oranyother"})
public class CacheHandlingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    if(httpReq.getRequestURI().contains("/yourresourcename/")) {
        httpResp.setDateHeader("Expires", ProvideTimeForCacheHere);
        httpResp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + ProvideTimeForCacheHere);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to apply cache headers globally across your servlets you could use a Filter.

Tomcat 7 has an [ExpiresFilter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/filters/ExpiresFilter.html) built in; for Tomcat 6 you could write your own, or [use a third-party library](http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/enabling-resource-caching-in-tomcat.html), to perform the same task.

Comment: I ported ExpiresFilter from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 6. See https://github.com/bnegrao/ExpiresFilter