# What options do I have to share readonly data across requests in a web application

Tags: database-design, web, architecture, share

We have a web application that needs to store about 200MB worth of data that will be accessed across user requests in a read-only fashion. The data is currently stored in a database. We want to bring it in memory in order to speed up reads. What are the best approaches to solving this problem? 
Should we go with some sort of static data structure that will be shared across requests? Should we have a separate process that initializes the data in memory and communication with requests via IPC? Or is there something that I am missing? Would memcached help with something like this? 
I don't know if this makes a difference, but the application is a mix of groovy/grails and java with postgres backend on apache.

Edit: Once loaded the data will not need any updates. It remains constant for the life of the web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all you have is 200MB data in the postgres database, then you can have an initialization phase(or later sync phase when data is updated) to read all data into memory as Java POJOs. And you web applications can use those POJOs to server incoming HTTP requests. No memcached is needed unless you find that you cannot fit all stuff in one server's memory space.

Comment: How would the POJOs be shared across the requests?

Comment: I am assuming you are using Servlet to handle all HTTP requests. Then using ServletContext to put any Map, ArrayList or dedicated cache object which will hold all the Java POJO classes. This can allow other servlets to get the cache object from the servlet context. Check the 2nd answers in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699996/java-web-application-how-to-implement-caching-techniques) which uses EHCache which is more advanced.

Comment: Another question in the same context ... would this still be a good solution if the cache grows to let's say larger than 2GB, again readonly, no updates or using something like memcached be a better approach then?

Comment: If the size will exceed single machine JVM maximum allowed memory, then it's worth considering options like EHCache, Memcached to allow cache spanning across multiple machines' memory. The programming model should be almost the same for your Servlet, but the backend implementation for the cache and interface to operation with the cache manager is different. In the previous post I mentioned, it has sample code for interacting with EHCache manager in Servlet code.